# Get customer data from id - magento2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0

how can we get the customer data from id not from customer session in Magento2.

Kindly let me know.

Answer (score 5):

Load the customer by using the api factory.  This is the correct way.

```
<?php

namespace Yourcompany\Customer\Helper {

/**
 * Eav data helper
 */
class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
    protected $customerRepository;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterfaceFactory $customerRepositoryFactory) {
        $this->customerRepository = $customerRepositoryFactory->create();
    }

    public function LoadCustomerById($customerId) {
         $cst = $this->customerRepository->getById($customerId);
         return $cst;
    } 

}

?>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can get all customer data from customer id in Magento 2. Here is the code snippet

```
<?php
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory')- 
>create();

$customerId = 1;

$customer = $customerFactory->load($customerId);

//fetch whole customer information
echo "<pre>";
print_r($customer->getData());

//fetch specific information
echo $customer->getEmail();
echo $customer->getFirstName();
echo $customer->getLastName();
```

You can also get customer billing address and shipping address from customer id. Full post is in this [link](http://www.codextblog.com/code-snippet/get-customer-information-customer-id-magento-2/)

For the demonstrated purpose I have used Objectmanager. One should always use  constructor method.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the code snippet to get customer data by using id programmatically in magento 2 version

```
    use \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap; 
    include('app/bootstrap.php'); 
    $bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
    $objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
    $url = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $storeManager = $url->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
    $state = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\State'); 
    $state->setAreaCode('frontend');
    $websiteId = $storeManager->getWebsite()->getWebsiteId();
    // Get Store ID
    $store = $storeManager->getStore();
    $storeId = $store->getStoreId();
    $customerFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory'); 
    $customer=$customerFactory->create();
    $customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId);
    //$customer->loadByEmail('example@gmail.com');// load customer by email address
    //echo $customer->getEntityId();
    $customer->load('1');// load customer by using ID
    $data= $customer->getData();
    print_r($data);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get customer data by id by following way

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Index;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{

    protected $_customer;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer $customer,
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
    )
    {
        $this->_customer = $customer;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

     public function getCustomer()
    {
        $customerId = '3'; //You customer ID
        $customer = $this->_customer->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('eq' => '3'));
        print_r($customer->getData());//Customer data by customer ID
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is recommended to use dependency injection instead of using object manager.

Create block like

```
namespace Lapisbard\General\Block;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;

class CustomerAccount extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template {

    public function __construct(
        Session $customerSession,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;

    }
    public function getCustomerName(){
        $this->_customerSession->getCustomer()->getName();
    }
}
```

And use it in your template like

```
<?php echo $block->getCustomerName(); ?>
```

Comment: in `__construct()` method you should add also `data` (array) argument. Take a look at some core blocks for example.

Comment: If there is no session, you can't get the customer using this method.  This makes sense if you are trying to load up a customer's data for use in other ways than during the customer's visit.

Answer (score 1):

```
 $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $customer = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Customer')->load($customerId);

    $xxx = $customer->getData('xxx');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $customer =  $this->objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Customer')->load(1);
```

Instead of objectManager you should use dependency injection.

Answer (score 0):

This is the old Ans Magento updated this
You can get customer data from following method also more options are available

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customer = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Customer')->load(1);
```

Also you can use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer for blocks using dependency injection.The main benefits of using object manager is it can be used in phtml.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing same problem when **Cache** enable I am not able to get customer session.But I find below solution

```
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Session
     */
    protected $_customerSession;

    public function __construct(Template\Context $context,
            \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
            \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository,
            \Magento\Customer\Model\SessionFactory $customerSession
        ) 
    {
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
        $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function getCustomerId(){
        $customer = $this->_customerSession->create();
        var_dump($customer->getCustomer()->getId());
    }
```

Use above code in block It is working even cache is enable.

**Second Solution:**

Add **cacheable="false"** in your xml

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
     <block class="Vendor\Modulename\Block\Customer" name="customer.session.data" template="Vendor_Modulename::customertab.phtml" cacheable="false" />
 </referenceContainer>
```

Add below code in block:

```
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Session
     */
    protected $_customerSession;

    /**
     * Construct
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
     */
    public function __construct(Template\Context $context,
            \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
            \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository,
            \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
        ) 
    {
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
        $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function getOrderData(){
        $customerId = $this->_customerSession->getCustomerId();
        var_dump($this->_customerSession->getCustomer());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Get Customer Details In Magento2 By Id**

```html
use Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory;

class CustomClass {
    /**
     * @var CustomerFactory
     */
    private $customerFactory;
 
    public function __construct(
        CustomerFactory $customerFactory,
    ) {
        $this->customerFactory = $customerFactory;
    }
    
    public function getCustomerDetails() {
    
        $customerId=6;
        // $customerId =$this->getCustomerIdByEmail();
        // $customerId =$this->getCustomerIdByMobile();
   
        $loadData =$this->customerFactory->create()->load($customerId);
        $allData = $loadData->getData());
        
        print_r($allData);
    }
}
```

**To Get The Customer ID By Email**

```
public function getCustomerIdByEmail() {
  $customerId = $this->customerFactory->create()->getCollection()
                ->addFieldToFilter('email', $email)
                ->getFirstItem()->getId();
}
```

**To Get The Customer ID By Mobile Number**

```
public function getCustomerIdByMobile() {
    $customerId = $this->customerFactory->create()->getCollection()
        ->addFieldToFilter('mobile_number', $mobile_number)
        ->getFirstItem()->getId();
}
```